# Why does Input mode work on iOS even though safari is not supported?

Tags: html, css

This is when the inputmode attribute is applied on Android and iOS.

supplement:
OS: iOS15
Browser: Safari

```html
<input type="text" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="1">
```

[image]

However, I know the inputmode doesn't work on Safari.

[image]

why does it work on Safari?

Comment: Because Apple has strange priorities. It's always been like this: iOS Safari supported `<input type="date">` for 10+ years before macOS Safari did.

Comment: @Terry I think the OP is asking about macOS Safari vs. iOS Safari. They are different browsers running separate branches of WebKit.

Comment: I may be missing something, are you not referring to the "Safari on iOS" column that displays it as supported since 12.2?

Comment: @Chris W. 

I got it!!!!!

Comment: Sorry... I had a misunderstanding

Comment: Thank you for comments, I close this because it was solved.